# How to combine multiple body classes

Tags: filters

My theme already has a specific body class filter for the colorscheme it uses. How can I also add a body class filter for the page name? Basically I want to combine these statements:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<body class="<?php echo get_stencil(); ?>">
```

I've been trying but I just keep getting error messages with variations like this:

```
 <body class="<?php echo get_stencil(); ?> <?php body_class(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

directly in the body tag line:

```
<body <?php body_class( get_stencil() ); ?>>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Adding_More_Classes

Answer (score 2):

Add following filter code in functions.php to add any custom class to body.

```
// Add specific CSS class by filter
add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
function my_class_names($classes) {
// add 'class-name' to the $classes array
$classes[] = 'class-name';
// return the $classes array
return $classes;
}
```